# How to add CaseComments, Attachments, Team Members and Histories as a list related to the RelatedList tag in a visualforce page for Case

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

as the question posed I would like to know how to add all these related lists on the case visualforce page. I have added others and they work perfect, but specifically with these (CaseComments, Attachments, Team Members and Histories ) gives the following error

'CaseComment' is not a valid child relationship name for entity Case

'Attachments' is not a valid child relationship name for entity Case

'TeamMembers' is not a valid child relationship name for entity Case

'Histories' is not a valid child relationship name for entity Case

Comment: yep -- you have discovered that some OOTB relationships can't be modeled with the `apex:relatedList` component. You need to follow the pattern in the link that glls posted above.  `Attachments` though is available with `NotesAndAttachments`

Answer (score 0):

There is a quick way to find the related list name. You have to a rest api describe call on the workbench. Related list name is **RelationshipName**.

[image]

Endpoint : /services/data/v42.0/sobjects/Case/describe

Comment: Yes, I already did and I get the error mentioned